# Is it possible to create a single file for a collection?

Tags: jekyll

I have a set of pages that are pretty similair, only a few attributes differ. In the collection docs it says I should create a single document for every item, like this:

```
_my_collection/
└── some_doc.md
└── more_doc.md
```

but that is not very convinient, I would rather create a single yaml-file with all the content in it:

my_collection.yaml

```
my_collection:
   some_doc:
      attribute_1: foo
      attribute_2: bar
   more_doc:
      attribute_1: foo
      attribute_2: bar
```

Is this at all possible?

Comment: It is possible but it depends what you want to do with that data, do you want to generate a single url for each file or have a page with all the data?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED FOLLOWING QUESTION CLARIFICATION:**

Not if you want to output pages. The file is the trigger to build a page. Except, as you point out, with a plugin/extension - which will not work on github.

Yes, if you are just referencing the values. Use something like:

`{{site.myCollection.collectionFile.some_doc.attribute_1}}`

Although this is probably better done as a data file inside your `_data` folder with something like:

`{{site.data.myDataFile.some_doc.attribute_1}}`

You can loop through values too in a file too - though be aware about how hash and arrays differ when you structure your file.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a really neat extension called [data_page_generator](https://github.com/avillafiorita/jekyll-datapage_gen/)

it can make pages out of yaml and csv and works out of the box.